# Let $V = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : y - z = 0 \}$, and let $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be an endomorphism such that ...

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : y - z = 0 \}$, and let $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be an endomorphism such that $V = \text{ker}(f)$ and $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $f$.

Which of the following is true?

(a) $\text{dim}(\text{Im}(f)) = 2$

(b) The characteristic polynomial of $f$ can be $-t(t + 1)^2$

(c) $f$ has three distinct eigenvalue

(d) $f$ is simple

The correct answer is (d), but I don't know how he arrived at that conclusion. Can you help me?

Comment: Well, you should be able to argue that (a), (b), and (c) are all false. What does it mean for $\mathbf f$ to be simple? At least you should be providing your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also do not know what you mean by f is simple but as mentioned above you can argue that all assumptions a,b,c are false the following way.

a)Since $ker(f)=V$ and $V$ is 2 dimensional than $Im(f)$ has to be 1 dimensional, by the dimensionequation for a linear map.

b) The characteristic polynomial can not be the following because that would mean that the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$ should be $1$, but its geometric multiplicity which is given by $dim(V)=dim(f-0*Id)=2$ is greater than $1$ , leads to a contradiction. Look up the inequality for algebraic and geometric multiplicity.($a(\lambda)<g(\lambda)$)

c)$f$ also can not have three distinct eigenvalues. If one of the eigenvalues were to be $0$ than you can lead the assumption to a contradiction by the above argumentation. If $0$ were no eigenvalue the kernel would than be trivial which is also a contradiction.

d) i am not sure what simple means

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\text{dim(Im}(f))+\text{dim(Ker}(f))=\text{dim}(\mathbb R^3)$.
$V$ is defined as the set $\{\underline x \in \mathbb R^3:y-z=0\}$, which has dimension equal to $2$ because the system $\begin{cases}x=\alpha&\alpha\in\mathbb R\\y=z=\beta &\beta\in\mathbb R\end{cases}$ has two free parameters.
This fact implies that the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue zero, which corresponds to the dimension of the eigenspace relative to the eigenvalue $\lambda= 0$, is equal to $2$ and also that $\text{dim(Im}(f))=3-2=1$.
For these reasons we can state that (a) and (b) are false. The second is false because the characteristic polynomial can't have the $t$ term with algebraic multiplicity one since $\forall \lambda\in\mathbb R$ eigenvalue $mg(\lambda)\le ma(\lambda)$.
Of course the characteristic polynomial $\chi(t)=t^2(t+1)$ doesn't have three distinct roots for the same facts I wrote for (a) and (b).